# FlutterFlow Firebase Custom Function simple query

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[image: Error Image]

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:math' as math;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:timeago/timeago.dart' as timeago;
import '../../flutter_flow/lat_lng.dart';
import '../../flutter_flow/place.dart';
import '../../flutter_flow/custom_functions.dart';
import '../../backend/backend.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import '../../auth/auth_util.dart';

String? userToNameFxn(DocumentReference? usr) {
  /// MODIFY CODE ONLY BELOW THIS LINE

  var tmp = '';

  // Get a reference to the Firestore database
  //final _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  // Get a reference to the "users" collection
  //CollectionReference users = _db.collection('users');

  // Define the ID of the user you want to retrieve
  String userId = "$usr?.id";

  // Retrieve the user with the specified ID
  /*DocumentReference user = users.document(userId);
  user.get().then((DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    // Print the user data
    tmp = snapshot.data as String;
  });

  final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  db
      .collection("users")
      .where("uid", isEqualTo: userId)
      .snapshots()
      .listen((event) {
    tmp = event.docs[0].data()["display_name"];
  });*/

  // Get a reference to the Firestore database
  var db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  // Create a reference to the "users" table
  var usersRef = db.collection('users');

  // Create a query to filter the documents by the "uid" field
  var query = usersRef.where('uid', isEqualTo: userId);

  // Get the first matching document
  query.get().then((querySnapshot) {
    if (querySnapshot.size > 0) {
      // There is a matching document, so you can get the data from the first result
      var firstResult = querySnapshot.docs[0];
      var data = firstResult.data();

      // Get the display_name field from the data
      var displayName = data['display_name'];
      tmp = displayName;
      // Do something with the display_name...
    } else {
      // There are no matching documents

      tmp = '';
    }
  });

  return tmp;

  /// MODIFY CODE ONLY ABOVE THIS LINE
}
```

All i am attempting to accomplish is to query firebase using dart inside the custom function tab.

The function will get DocumentReference  as a parameter and will return the the display_name as a string. I can't find a direct way to accomplish this method without facing errors in FF.

I can see that FF is not recognizing Firebase Library.

I have tried multiple approaches (the ones that are commented), but it does not seem to work.

I tried a different code:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:math' as math;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:timeago/timeago.dart' as timeago;
import '../../flutter_flow/lat_lng.dart';
import '../../flutter_flow/place.dart';
import '../../flutter_flow/custom_functions.dart';
import '../../backend/backend.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import '../../auth/auth_util.dart';

String? userToNameFxn(DocumentReference? usr) {
  /// MODIFY CODE ONLY BELOW THIS LINE

  // Get a reference to the Firestore database
  final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  // Create a reference to the "users" table
  var usersRef = db.collection('users');

  // Create a query to filter the documents by the "uid" field
  var query = usersRef.where('uid', isEqualTo: usr?.id);

  // Get the first matching document
  query.get().then((querySnapshot) {
    if (querySnapshot.size > 0) {
      // There is a matching document, so you can get the data from the first result
      var firstResult = querySnapshot.docs[0];
      var data = firstResult.data();

      // Get the display_name field from the data
      var displayName = data['display_name'];
      return displayName;
    }
  });
  return '';

  /// MODIFY CODE ONLY ABOVE THIS LINE
}
```

Yet i am getting same error again.

[image: Error Image While Testing the Function]

Comment: What version of firestore are you using?

Comment: I guess it the problem is mainly that firebase doesn't work in custom functions, insead use custom actions for that.

Answer (score 1):

For an easy solution, you can use `custom action` as [@Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4061346/joe) mentioned in the comments. By using custom actions you are able to use `await`. You can do it as follow in an action:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:math' as math;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:timeago/timeago.dart' as timeago;
import '../../flutter_flow/lat_lng.dart';
import '../../flutter_flow/place.dart';
import '../../flutter_flow/custom_functions.dart';
import '../../backend/backend.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import '../../auth/auth_util.dart';

String? userToNameFxn(DocumentReference? userRef) async{
  /// MODIFY CODE ONLY BELOW THIS LINE
  
  if(userRef == null){
    return ''; // or null if you want!
  }
  final userSnapshot = await userRef.get();
  final user = userSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
  return data['display_name'] ?? ''; // or null if you want!

  /// MODIFY CODE ONLY ABOVE THIS LINE
}
```

Note that when you have the reference of the document, you can easily get its data directly by that.

Also if this user reference is for the current user/app's user, you have access to the user document all over the FF. You can easily use the users' fields and do not need to write custom actions and functions for them.